# Custom placeholders for custom validation rules in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I've created a set of custom validation rules in my Laravel application. I first created a `validators.php` file which is in the `App\Http` directory:

```
/**
 * Require a certain number of parameters to be present.
 *
 * @param  int     $count
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @param  string  $rule
 * @return void
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */

    function requireParameterCount($count, $parameters, $rule) {

        if (count($parameters) < $count):
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Validation rule $rule requires at least $count parameters.");
        endif;

    }


/**
 * Validate the width of an image is less than the maximum value.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return bool
 */

    $validator->extend('image_width_max', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

        requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'image_width_max');

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($value);

        if ($width >= $parameters[0]):
            return false;
        endif;

        return true;

    });
```

I'm then adding including this in my `AppServiceProvider.php` file (while also adding `use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;` at the top of this file):

```
public function boot(Factory $validator) {

    require_once app_path('Http/validators.php');

}
```

Then in my form request file, I can call the custom validation rule, like so:

```
$rules = [
    'image' => 'required|image|image_width:50,800',
];
```

Then in the Laravel `validation.php` file located in the `resources/lang/en` directory, I'm adding another key/value to the array to display an error message if the validation returns false and fails, like so:

```
'image_width' => 'The :attribute width must be between :min and :max pixels.',
```

Everything works fine, it checks the image correctly, displays the error message if it fails, but I'm not sure how to replace `:min` and `:max` with the values declared in the form request file (50,800), the same way `:attribute` is replaced with the forms field name. So currently it displays:

`The image width must be between :min and :max pixels.`

Whereas I want it to display like this

`The image width must be between 50 and 800 pixels.`

I've seen some `replace*` functions in the master `Validator.php` file `(vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumiate/Validation/)`, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to get it to work with my own custom validation rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't used it this way but you can probably use:

```
$validator->replacer('image_width_max',
    function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace([':min', ':max'], [$parameters[0], $parameters[1]], $message);
    });
```

Comment: I'll give this a test shortly and let you know how I get on, thanks man!

Comment: Works a treat, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I used:

In composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/Validators"
    ],
```

In App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->validator->resolver(
        function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
}
```

In App/Validators/CustomValidator.php

```
namespace App\Validators;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    // This is my custom validator to check unique with
    public function validateUniqueWith($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $this->requireParameterCount(4, $parameters, 'unique_with');
        $parameters    = array_map('trim', $parameters);
        $parameters[1] = strtolower($parameters[1] == '' ? $attribute : $parameters[1]);
        list($table, $column, $withColumn, $withValue) = $parameters;

        return DB::table($table)->where($column, '=', $value)->where($withColumn, '=', $withValue)->count() == 0;
    }

    // All you have to do is create this function changing
    // 'validate' to 'replace' in the function name
    protected function replaceUniqueWith($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        return str_replace([':name'], $parameters[4], $message);
    }
}
```

> :name is replace by $parameters[4] in this replaceUniqueWith function

In App/resources/lang/en/validation.php

```
<?php
return [
    'unique_with' => 'The :attribute has already been taken in the :name.',
];
```

In my controller, I call this validator like this:

```
$organizationId = session('organization')['id'];    
$this->validate($request, [
    'product_short_title' => "uniqueWith:products,short_title,
                              organization_id,$organizationId,
                              Organization",
]);
```

This is what it looks like in my form :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this in Laravel 5.4:

*AppServiceProvider.php*

```
public function boot()
{
    \Validator::extend('contains_field', 'App\Validators\ContainsFieldValidator@validate');
    \Validator::replacer('contains_field', 'App\Validators\ContainsFieldValidator@replace');
}
```

*App\Validators\ContainsFieldValidator.php*

```
class ContainsFieldValidator
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, Validator $validator)
    {
        $required = $parameters[0];
        $requiredDefault = isset($parameters[1]) ?: null;

        if (!$required && !$requiredDefault) {
            return false;
        }

        $requiredValue = isset($validator->attributes()[$required]) ? $validator->attributes()[$required] : $requiredDefault;

        return !(strpos($value, $requiredValue) === false);
    }

    public function replace($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        return str_replace([':required'], str_replace('_', ' ', $parameters[0]), $message);
    }
}
```